# Why do I see three different Python installations in “/usr/bin” in macOS 10.15 beta?

Tags: python, python3

I am currently running the macOS 10.15 beta and am having some issues with my Python installations. For some reason, I have `python`, `python2` and `python3` all in my `/usr/bin` folder.

I am not sure why I have all three of these, but could someone advise as to what is going on here and whether Mac now natively comes with Python3.

Comment: Voting to close because on macOS Mojave (10.4) there are two installs of Python; whether that changes in 10.5 is speculation in the context of a beta. If you are using beta software and have a question about the setup and config of it, the only people who can answer that is the source of the beta software meaning Apple themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Python applications/scripts are quite particular about what version they use, and will often require a particular version to be installed before they function correctly (or at all).

It's likely you use all 3 of these versions without even realising it.